# CAML Query for lookup field with multi values

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

What is the caml query for a Lookup field with multi values?

So far, I am using the following without success (it just throws an error).
My Lookup column is:

```
Lookup
-------
2;3
2
3;4

<Contains><FieldRef Name="LookupColumn"/><Value Type="LookupMulti">2</Value></Contains>
```

What is wrong with that query??

Comment: Where are you testing this query? In a Caml query builder or directly in a .net application?

Comment: directly in a .net application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your query inside a Where clause/tag.

```
<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="LookupColumn"/><Value Type="LookupMulti">2</Value></Contains></Where>
```

Comment: `<FieldRef Name='Account' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Text'>1</Value>` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

```
SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
oQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"LookupColumn\" LookupId=\"TRUE\"/><Value Type=\"LookupMulti\">2</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

Comment: I noticed you are using Eq, does it mean lookup with multiple values does not support Contains?

Comment: If you are using it with LookupId=True it will result in wrong return values.

Comment: I just tried this in a SharePoint 2013 environment. This worked, and the accepted answer didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup field has ID and value associated with it something like '2|val'
If you specifically want to get values based on value, then your query should look like below,

`<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="LookupColumn"/><Value Type="LookupMulti">val</Value></Eq></Where>`
,

And if you want to query Lookup column based on LookupId, query should be,

`<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='MultiLookupFieldName' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='LookupMulti'>" + id + "</Value></Eq></Where>`

To understand the difference between 
`<Eq>` and `<Contains>` particalurly for Lookup column, follow the URl,
https://naimmurati.wordpress.com/2013/12/03/multi-lookup-fields-in-caml-queries-eq-vs-contains/